# Entity Framework 6 : lazy loading doesn't work

Tags: entity-framework, lazy-loading

The property is defined as `virtual`. But before I access the order property, the order entity's data has been loaded, why?

[image: debug screenshots]

Full source code:

[image: full source code]

Comment: Learn [how to use code block](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) to show your code instead of post it in image

Comment: if post is mostly code, Stack Overflow doesn't allow me to submit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of things:

When you state: doesn't work, you are getting an Order back, but the $ figure is 0.0 when you expect a different value? You appear have 2x order records, but based on what is coming back you're expecting a non-zero figure, are both records non-zero? In your debug view, expand the "Orders" in the pop-up context menu, this will reveal what order details EF has loaded.

Firstly you should be careful around the use of "OrDefault" renditions of the methods. Your code is assuming that a value is returned. In these cases you're better off using `Single()` or `First()` as applicable.

Additionally, when using `First` you should be specifying an `OrderBy` clause to ensure that there is a reliable ordering.

`SaveChanges` Should only be called if you modify data.

Lastly, lazy loading is an enabler for loading infrequently used data on demand. You should largely work to avoid relying on lazy-load calls. If you need the entire entities and you know you are going to use orders, then eager-load them.

I.e.

```
using (var context = new EfContext())
{
  var customer = context.Customers
    .Include(c => c.Orders)
    .Single(c => c.CustomerId = customerId);
  // Do stuff...
}
```

If you want just 1 applicable order for a given employee then consider using `Select` to retrieve it:

I.e.

```
using (var context = new EfContext())
{
  var data = context.Customers.Where(c => c.CustomerId = customerId)
    .Select(c => new { Customer = c, FirstOrder = c.Orders.OrderBy(o => o.OrderDate).FirstOrDefault()})
    .Single();
  // Do Stuff...
}
```

This will give you an anonymous type containing the Customer (without eager loading the orders) and the matching first order.

Better is just to use `Select` to retrieve the specific fields you need from customer and order(s). This reduces the amount of data (rows and columns) pulled back from the database.

Comment: thank you for your reply,this is just a demo, I'm learning Entity framework ,I want to  find out how the Lazy loading works.In my opinion, the related Orders will be loaded the first time the Orders navigation property is accessed,But At the program breakpoint, the Orders navigation property has not be accessed,why is the order records loaded？

Comment: The orders would not be loaded at the breakpoint, the code you stopped on would trigger the load. When using a debugger with EF that can kind of skew the behaviour since execution is effectively paused, yet you want to inspect an EF proxy which will want to kick off a load. Sometimes you get a warning about all execution paths needing to run, but I don't find it reliable. Once you step past that line, the Orders should be loaded.

Answer (score 0):

sorry,It looks like the problem of visual studio，When the call statement is commented,the order table's sql querie no longer being executed,but when the call statement is included,although the breakpoint is set,the order table's sql querie still be executed.

visual studio debug execute the Expression automatically

[comment the staement](https://i.stack.imgur.com/APLJR.png)

[sql profiler](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C2Vab.png)

[include the statement](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Eq2hW.png)

[sql profiler](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tJt3P.png)